# Counting what age groups people fall into for each month

Tags: excel, count, sum

I am very far from being an excel expert, I'm trying to pick it up fast and have so far eventually picked up how to do what I need but am now stumped, so would really appreciate some help.

Basically I have to record a lot of client data and then have a worksheet set up to collect stats. So for example to date we've had 154 clients, 90 of which are female and 64 are male, so my stat worksheet is set up to give me a running total as well as month/quarter/year total. I've set that all up fine the running total male formula is `=COUNTIF(Registration!R3:R1000,B68)` and female is `=COUNTIF(Registration!R3:R1000,B69)` and Nov 15's total of males is `=SUMPRODUCT(--(Registration!AH3:AH1000>=D1+0),--(Registration!AH3:AH1000<=D2+0),--(Registration!R3:R1000='Sarah Data'!M3))` with females formula being `=SUMPRODUCT(--(Registration!AH3:AH1000>=D1+0),--(Registration!AH3:AH1000<=D2+0),--(Registration!R3:R1000='Sarah Data'!M4))`

So now I come to having to report on what age bracket people fall into. First I had to have a formula to put DOB's into age at sign up which I use `=INT((AH3-D3)/365)` then I had to find away to change the age into the age bracket so in the next cell I inserted a vlookup as follows `=VLOOKUP(AQ3,Age,2,FALSE)` but when I came to inputting the formula to count all the 16-24 who had signed up in Nov 15 by doing

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Registration!AH3:AH1000>=D1+0),--(Registration!AH3:AH1000<=D2+0),--(Registration!AR3:AR1000='Sarah Data'!B70))` or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Registration!AH3:AH1000>=D1+0),--(Registration!AH3:AH1000<=D2+0),--(Registration!AR3:AR1000= "16 - 24"))
```

I thought this might have something to do with counting figures not text so I did another V look up in the next column after the age brackets so that it would display a if 16 - 24, b if 25 - 50 and so on which was as follows

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Registration!AH3:AH1000>=D1+0),--(Registration!AH3:AH1000<=D2+0),--(Registration!AS3:AS1000="A"))` or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Registration!AH3:AH1000>=D1+0),--(Registration!AH3:AH1000<=D2+0),--(Registration!AS3:AS1000='Sarah Data'!C62))
```

But neither will work.

Comment: Why do so much calculation when you can select the entire table and create a Pivot Table?

Comment: Please attach sample data set.

Comment: I've never used a pivot table

Comment: Read this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Quick-start-Create-a-PivotTable-report-0c220f35-e478-49aa-beaf-24018b7f0f64

Comment: "I am very far from being an excel expert," <-- totally disagree..  || you're on your way to be one.. || It's a neatly composed/asked question..  /[^_^]